# send functions to a directive in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my AngularJS project, I can pass scope functions into a directive, if the directive is used by the top-level view. I can also successfully pass parameters to those functions, invoking with the ({obj: mapping}) syntax.

If a higher-level directive is used, and that higher-level directive needs to pass the function to the low-level (inner most) directive, I have limited success. I can pass scope functions if the scope functions do not need a parameter when invoked by the low-level directive. However I have not been able to make the low-level directive pass a parameter if the scope function takes a parameter.

I've tried many variations on the syntax for passing functions at various levels, using (), not using (), using a placeholder at various spots, using object mapping by the directive ({someData: 'arg'}).

The example below works, but how do I change it to pass an argument in the low-level directive?

Here is the [plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9tbhVhtUWEFihuNX3oxq?p=preview).

JS code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'placeholder';

  $scope.setName = function(aName) {
    aName = aName || 'it was undefined';
    $scope.name = aName; //wish i could make this be 'low level'
  };
});

app.directive('lowLevel', function() {
  return {
    // todo: pass arg, e.g. action('low level')
    template: '<div><span ng-click="action(\'low level\')">click me once</span></div>',
    scope: {
      action: '&'
    }
  }
});

app.directive('highLevel', function(){
  return {
    template: '<div><low-level action="func({val: \'high level\'})"></low-level></div>',
    scope: {
      func: '&'
    }
  }
});
```

HTML usage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <high-level func="setName(val)"></high-level>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'placeholder';
  
  $scope.setName = function(aName) {
    aName = aName || 'it was undefined';
    $scope.name = aName; //wish i could make this be 'low level'
  };
});

app.directive('lowLevel', function() {
  return {
    // todo: pass arg, e.g. action('johnny')
    restrict:'E',
    template: '<div><span ng-click="action({val: \'low level\'})">click me once</span></div>',
    scope: {
      action: '&'
    }
  }
});

app.directive('highLevel', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    template: '<div><low-level action="func({val: val})"></low-level></div>',
    scope: {
      func: '&'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

span:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

span {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <high-level func="setName(val)"></high-level>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use this in your template to pass along the argument:

```
template: '<div><low-level action="func({val: val})"></low-level></div>',
```